# How to export pdfTable that is not equal or divisible with the pdfCell count?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, datagridview, itext, cell

I am currently doing a loop from a *DataGridView* that will read each selected item and create a cell with the item's barcode in it (cells to be exported depends on the quantity the user had input), but If I tried to export 1 barcode label (1 pdfCell) it wouldn't export and says 'the pdfTable is empty' because I have a pdfTable.Columns(5) which is means that my table has a column count of 5. So as long as I try to export cell quantities that are not divisible by 5 it wouldn't export.

Example 1: Item - Banana (10 Barcodes to print) - Exported

Example 2: Item - Apple (1 Barcode to print) - Not Exported (PDFTable is Empty) because 1(one) does not cover a single row of the pdfTable with a column count which is 5(five).

Here is my code for the 'Print Barcode Labels Button' :

```
Public Function print_itembarcodes(lbl169 As Label)
    Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(5)
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3
    pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100
    pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

    For i As Integer = 0 To Admin_Menu.BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows.Count - 1
        Admin_Menu.Label169.Text = Admin_Menu.BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value 'Item Barcode'
        Barcode.process_printbarcode(Admin_Menu.Label169)  'Make barcode image function'
        save_printbarcode() 'Save barcode to desktop function'

        For j As Integer = 0 To Admin_Menu.BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value 'Quantity of barcodes to be printed per item'
            pdfTable.AddCell(create_barcodecell) 'Add cell with barcode function'
        Next

    Next


    Try

        'Exporting to PDF
        Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Temp\"
        If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
        End If
        Using stream As New FileStream(folderPath & "temp2.pdf", FileMode.Create)
            Dim pdfdoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 15.0F, 15.0F, 10.0F, 20.0F)
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfdoc, stream)
            pdfdoc.Open()
            pdfdoc.Add(pdfTable) 'Table Declaration'
            pdfdoc.Close()
            stream.Close()


            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Temp\\temp2.pdf")

        End Using


    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try

    Return True
End Function
```

Here is my code for creating a cell with barcode :

```
Public Function create_barcodecell()
    Dim SaveFileDialog1 = "D:\School\Capstone\Sta. Lucia East Bowling and Billiard Hall Management System\Item Barcodes\"
    Dim Barcode2 As Image = Image.GetInstance(SaveFileDialog1 + Admin_Menu.Label169.Text + ".jpg") 'Barcode Image'
    Barcode2.ScaleAbsolute(80.0F, 25.0F)
    img.ScalePercent(15.0F) 'Company Logo Image'
    img.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_RIGHT


    Dim titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8)
    Dim paragraph As New Paragraph()

    paragraph.Add(New Chunk(img, 0, 0))
    paragraph.Add(New Chunk("      Item Tag", titleFont))

    Dim pdfCell As New PdfPCell
    pdfCell.UseVariableBorders = True
    pdfCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.GRAY
    pdfCell.BorderColorLeft = BaseColor.GREEN
    pdfCell.BorderColorRight = BaseColor.GREEN
    pdfCell.BorderColorTop = BaseColor.GREEN
    pdfCell.BorderColorBottom = BaseColor.GREEN


    pdfCell.AddElement(paragraph)
    pdfCell.AddElement(Barcode2)
    pdfCell.AddElement(New Paragraph("      " + Admin_Menu.Label169.Text, titleFont))


    Return pdfCell
End Function
```

Comment: a) Turn on `Option Strict` b) your post has 3 close votes on it (probably) because there is no clear problem statement.  The *PdfTable/Document is empty* is tacked on as sort of an oh-by-the-way clause c) We dont know any more about your app that wheat you post and tell us.  So the mention of `BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows(i).cells(5).value` tells us nothing because we dont know what col 5 represents.  d) There are several other things that are unclear - what is Admin_menu?

Comment: @Plutonix Column 5 is the Value of the Quantity of the Barcode Labels the user wants to print for that item. For example, Item-Banana (5 Barcodes to print) 5 is the Column 5 value which is the Barcodes to print... Admin_Menu is the form where all the controls mentioned in my post are in.

Comment: @Plutonix I’m guessing my errors lie on the ‘For j as integer = 0 to Admin_Menu.BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value’ loop because when I changed that value to ‘3’ it printed 4 barcode labels but when I changed it to other numbers it came back to being an empty table again...

Comment: @Plutonix I also tried to pass the column 5 value to an integer variable and the table is still empty so I tried to confirm if it reads the column 5 value by passing it to a msgbox and it reads the value but still when I apply it to the loop the table is still empty

Comment: When you say the table is empty, do you mean the *document* or the pdfTable you created? I am guessing that perhaps 5 is too many and wont inside the margins.  This should be easy to see using the debugger.

Comment: @Plutonix The pdfTable I created is empty... Cause when I try to add a paragraph... The paragraph is there when I exported it and the pdfTable wasn’t.... What do you mean 5 is too many? My pdfTable has 4 columns so it will go down the next row after 4 barcode labels... Also if column 5 is too many I think the error won’t say pdfTable is empty

Comment: @Plutonix also the standard column 5 value is 1 so it cannot be too many... Cause in my case when you select an item it is automatically set to 1 barcode labels to print but you can edit it if you want... So the standard value is 1 barcode label

Comment: @Plutonix I think I know what the problem really is yet still can't figure out how to fix it. The cells need to be in par or divisible with the number of columns in order to print for example I changed the number of columns to 5. Means I can only print the cells if the quantity is divisible by 5 like 5,10,20,100. How can I fix this? Because I need for it to be flexible even printing a single barcode label...

Comment: If the remaining cells in that table row are to be empty ones, how about simply adding additional empty cells until you do have a number of cells divisible by 5?

Comment: @mkl how can I add empty cells? and how can I do that adding empty cells until it is divisible by 5?

Comment: @mkl you can modify my code and post an answer if you like... But if you feel like discussing it it’s fine either way

Comment: @Plutonix Do you know the code for line spacing in pdfCells? Because the distance between my image and paragraphs are just too informal for me..

Comment: @mkl you too bro...

Comment: * Also if ... I think the error won’t say pdfTable is empty*  Nowhere in the first five edits of your post did you mention an error or what the error error message.

Comment: @Plutonix because there is no error in my code it’s just the cells are increasing by one... The error will only appear when I edit my code and change the start of my loop at 1 instead of 0 and print 1 barcode label...

Comment: @Plutonix the error will say ‘The document has no pages’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is

> So as long as I try to export cell quantities that are not divisible by 5 it wouldn't export.

If the remaining cells in that table row are to be empty ones, you can solve this by simply adding additional empty cells until you do have a number of cells divisible by 5.

> how can I add empty cells?

I have not done any VB programming since the start of this century, so the syntax might need some correction, but basically you simply do

```
pdfTable.AddCell(New PdfPCell())
```

to add a new empty cell to `pdfTable`.

> and how can I do that adding empty cells until it is divisible by 5?

Count the number of cells you have added already and add until the count can be divided by 5 without remainder.

```
Dim Count as Integer = 0
For j As Integer = 1 To Admin_Menu.BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value 'Quantity of barcodes to be printed per item'
    pdfTable.AddCell(create_barcodecell) 'Add cell with barcode function'
    Count = Count + 1
Next
While count Mod 5 <> 0
    pdfTable.AddCell(New PdfPCell())
    Count = Count + 1
End While
```

(I'm not sure about VB details anymore, in particular whether `j` still exists outside the former `For` loop and which value it has. Depending on that you may not need a separate counter...)

Comment: I have one last problem now.. Whenever I print some numbers not divisible by 5. The cell numbers go up by 1. Like 6 become 7. 1 become 2. And when I try to subract the cell value by 1. It doesn't work

Comment: I'm not talking about the empty cells. I'm talking about the cells with barcodes I generated

Comment: @LuciferRodstark Ah, you probably should start your loops at 1. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: already tried that too... If I print 1 barcode it says pdfTable is empty cause I started at 1. When I print 6 barcodes it only prints 5 don't know why

Comment: That is weird. You probably should step through the code in a debugger to investigate which loop really is executed how often for which values.

Comment: how do I do that

Comment: Visual Studio should allow you to debug an application. As mentioned above, I'm not into VB anymore, so I don't know specifics. Usually, though, if one has used a debugger before, the usage is quite intuitive.

Comment: Corrected the second loop - it ran the wrong number of times.

Comment: why did you make it while? Also I think the empty cells got nothing to do with the off by one error because the off by one error applies to the cells with content in it not those empty ones

Comment: @LuciferRodstark Have a look at my answer to your other question. There I simplified your code using the values you claimed the variables should have, and the simplified code runs correctly with the first loop starting at one and the second one continuing to run until `Count` is a multiple of the number of cells per row. If the behavior in your code seems to indicate differently, therefore, your variables do not consistently contain what you assume they do.