# Loop for PDF Cells always Off by One

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, pdf, itext

I am trying to make a barcode label printer through cells. I have a pdfTable that has 3 columns. But everytime I tried to export the pdfTable with a cell count that is not equal or divisible by 3 (which is the number of columns), the cell count are always increasing or off by 1.

For example :

- Tried to export 30 cells which is divisible to the pdfTable columns which is 3 (works fine)
- Tried to export 1 or 10 cells which is not divisible to the pdfTable columns which is 3 (cell count are always off by 1). Results are like 1 cell become 2 cells and 10 cells become 11 cells.

I always check if there is something wrong with my loop that causes the cells to increase by 1 but I can't find anything.

Here is my code for exporting a PDF :

```
Public Function print_itembarcodes(lbl169 As Label)
    Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(3) 'pdfTable Column Count'
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3
    pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100
    pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER
    Dim emptyCell As New PdfPCell
    emptyCell.Border = 0
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To Admin_Menu.BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows.Count - 1 'Read item one by one'
        Admin_Menu.Label169.Text = Admin_Menu.BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
        Admin_Menu.Label170.Text = Admin_Menu.BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        Admin_Menu.Label171.Text = Admin_Menu.BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
        Barcode.process_printbarcode(Admin_Menu.Label169)
        save_printbarcode()


        For j As Integer = 0 To Admin_Menu.BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value 'Cell quantity to be exported for one item'
            pdfTable.AddCell(create_barcodecell) 'Create a cell with barcode'
            count = count + 1
        Next

    Next

    For k As Integer = 0 To count Mod 3
        pdfTable.AddCell(emptyCell)
    Next
    count = 0

    Try

        'Exporting to PDF'
        Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Temp\"
        If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
        End If
        Using stream As New FileStream(folderPath & "temp2.pdf", FileMode.Create)
            Dim pdfdoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 15.0F, 15.0F, 10.0F, 20.0F)
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfdoc, stream)
            pdfdoc.Open()
            pdfdoc.Add(pdfTable)
            pdfdoc.Close()
            stream.Close()


            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Temp\\temp2.pdf")

        End Using


    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try

    Return True
End Function
```

Here is my code for the function of creating a cell with barcode :

```
Public Function create_barcodecell()
    Dim SaveFileDialog1 = "D:\School\Capstone\Sta. Lucia East Bowling and Billiard Hall Management System\Item Barcodes\"
    Dim Barcode2 As Image = Image.GetInstance(SaveFileDialog1 + Admin_Menu.Label169.Text + ".png")
    Barcode2.ScaleAbsolute(170.0F, 50.0F)
    img.ScalePercent(20.0F)
    img.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER
    Dim itemname, itemprice, itemcode As New Paragraph
    itemname.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
    itemprice.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
    itemcode.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER


    Dim codeFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 10)
    Dim tagFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8)
    Dim priceFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 11)
    codeFont.Color = BaseColor.WHITE
    tagFont.Color = BaseColor.WHITE
    priceFont.Color = BaseColor.WHITE


    itemname.Add(New Chunk(Admin_Menu.Label170.Text, tagFont))
    itemprice.Add(New Chunk("P " + Admin_Menu.Label171.Text + ".00", priceFont))
    itemcode.Add(New Chunk(Admin_Menu.Label169.Text, codeFont))


    Dim pdfCell As New PdfPCell
    pdfCell.UseVariableBorders = True
    pdfCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.RED
    pdfCell.BorderColorLeft = BaseColor.BLACK
    pdfCell.BorderColorRight = BaseColor.BLACK
    pdfCell.BorderColorTop = BaseColor.BLACK
    pdfCell.BorderColorBottom = BaseColor.BLACK
    pdfCell.PaddingTop = 10
    pdfCell.PaddingBottom = 10
    pdfCell.PaddingLeft = 8
    pdfCell.PaddingRight = 10

    pdfCell.AddElement(img)
    pdfCell.AddElement(itemname)
    pdfCell.AddElement(Barcode2)
    pdfCell.AddElement(itemcode)
    pdfCell.AddElement(itemprice)


    Return pdfCell
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop started by

```
For j As Integer = 0 To Admin_Menu.BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value 'Cell quantity to be exported for one item'
```

executes `Admin_Menu.BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value + 1` times. You might want to start with the value `1` instead of `0` to get rid of the *off-by-one*.

The loop started by

```
For k As Integer = 0 To count Mod 3
```

executes `(count Mod 3) + 1` times.

My first idea was that you might also want to start with the value `1` instead of `0`, after all if `Count` already is a multiple of 3, you don't want it to run at all.

When I set up a simplified version of your program, though, in which I started that loop at 1, I got an exception, too. Thus, I reconsidered the actual purpose of that extra loop (which I myself recommended in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47571945/1729265)) and figured out that the number of iterations was completely wrong to start with:

For `Count = 1` one needs 2 extra iterations, for `Count = 2` one needs 1 extra iteration, for `Count = 3` none is needed, for `Count = 4` one needs 2 extra iterations, ...

So, one does not need `Count Mod 3` iterations of the second loop at all but instead `(3 - (Count Mod 3)) Mod 3` iterations, or more simple

```
While count Mod 3 <> 0
    pdfTable.AddCell(emptyCell)
    count = count + 1
End While
```

which also is what intuition should dictate: Continue adding empty cells until the cell count is a multiple of 3...

#### The test code

I simplified your code to be able to run it at all, after all I don't have those many variables you use. The final version (including the fixes mentioned above, the first loop starting at 1, the second one using the `While` now) was this:

```
Public Sub CreateTableLuciferRodstark(filledCells As Integer, fileName As String)
    Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(3) 'pdfTable Column Count'
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3
    pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100
    pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

    Dim emptyCell As New PdfPCell
    emptyCell.Border = 0

    Dim count As Integer = 0

    For j As Integer = 1 To filledCells
        pdfTable.AddCell(create_barcodecell) 'Create a cell with barcode'
        count = count + 1
    Next

    While count Mod 3 <> 0
        pdfTable.AddCell(emptyCell)
        count = count + 1
    End While

    Using stream As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create)
        Dim pdfdoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 15.0F, 15.0F, 10.0F, 20.0F)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfdoc, stream)
        pdfdoc.Open()
        pdfdoc.Add(pdfTable)
        pdfdoc.Close()
    End Using
End Sub

Public Function create_barcodecell()
    Dim pdfCell As New PdfPCell
    pdfCell.UseVariableBorders = True
    pdfCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.RED
    pdfCell.BorderColorLeft = BaseColor.BLACK
    pdfCell.BorderColorRight = BaseColor.BLACK
    pdfCell.BorderColorTop = BaseColor.BLACK
    pdfCell.BorderColorBottom = BaseColor.BLACK
    pdfCell.PaddingTop = 10
    pdfCell.PaddingBottom = 10
    pdfCell.PaddingLeft = 8
    pdfCell.PaddingRight = 10

    pdfCell.AddElement(New Paragraph("an item"))
    pdfCell.AddElement(New Paragraph("a code"))
    pdfCell.AddElement(New Paragraph("a price"))

    Return pdfCell
End Function
```

I ran the code for 1 to 6 filled cells:

```
CreateTableLuciferRodstark(1, "Table1of3.pdf")
CreateTableLuciferRodstark(2, "Table2of3.pdf")
CreateTableLuciferRodstark(3, "Table3of3.pdf")
CreateTableLuciferRodstark(4, "Table4of3.pdf")
CreateTableLuciferRodstark(5, "Table5of3.pdf")
CreateTableLuciferRodstark(6, "Table6of3.pdf")
```

and the results are:

Table1of3.pdf:

[image: Table1of3.pdf]

Table2of3.pdf:

[image: Table2of3.pdf]

Table3of3.pdf:

[image]

Table4of3.pdf:

[image]

Table5of3.pdf:

[image]

Table6of3.pdf:

[image]

Comment: May I ask why would you add 1 to the value when it’s already off by one... If I do that would that make the cells off by two now ?

Comment: *"why would you add 1 to the value"* - I would add 1 to the starting value, increasing it from 0 to 1. Thus, there would be no loop iteration for the value 0 anymore. Thus, there would be one iteration less.

Comment: you mean the ‘j as integer = 0 into 1’ or the ‘Admin_Menu.BarcodePrintListGrid.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value + 1’ ? Because if you do the ‘j as integer = 0 into 1’ I already tried that yesterday remember?

Comment: I remember. But that does not make sense. Yesterday I proposed debugging by stepping through the code, watching out for which loop really executes how often. Have you done that? What was the result?

Comment: I know... I turn on my Option Strict On which is like the debugger in VB... But when I try to run my system it works just fine no errors, just the off by one error in the loop that doesn’t cause a crash.. I also tried to pass the count value to a msgbox to know if the loop really is increasing by one and it does...

Comment: *"I turn on my Option Strict On which is like the debugger in VB"* - No. That option is no debugger, it merely enforces a less dirty programming style. Stepping through a program is something entirely different. And if you don't want to do that, you may instead use the old debugging style, add console outputs at every interesting point.

Comment: Is it hard to do? I’m not very familiar with stepping through the code with a debugger thing

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=debugger+visual+studio should give you some backgrounds, in particular msdn articles and youtube videos.

Comment: How would the debugger help me if there is no literal error in this... Just the iteration of the loop... Would the debugger still locate it and tell me what should I do like a official error message?

Comment: Using the debugger you can step through your program. Thus, you can determine whether for a given input it executes the program lines as you expect; furthermore, it allows you to inspect variable contents in any such situation. With the changes I proposed in my answer your code should add the correct number of cells to the table. As you say it doesn't, there appear to be some variables whose contents are not what you think they are (or change unexpectedly). To analyse such issues, you can use a debugger.

Comment: I’m also thinking that if my loop has sort of using a used variable so I would try to declare different set of variables this time then if that doesn’t work I’m going through a debugger

Comment: Ah, I have to admit there was an error in the answer I gave to your previous question. I'll correct that and come back here again.

Comment: May I ask, so the error in our answer really was is that the empty cells are causing off by one iterations? They’re the reason why I cannot start the loop at 1?

Comment: The original empty cells loop was *not* causing the off-by-one, it was causing the error you mentioned in a comment at the other question: *"If I print 1 barcode it says pdfTable is empty cause I started at 1"*, so you could say it was *the reason why you could not start the loop at 1*. The off-by-one was caused by the `j` loop starting at 0.

Comment: But mine has a DataGridView per item right? So is my code right about resetting the count to 0 if all the item has been scanned and all the loop is done...

Comment: You can set it to anything you want as it is not used anymore thereafter.

Comment: Thanks bro!!! It works now... Thank you for helping me even though I'm getting downvotes on my questions.. Till next time